# exploiting CVE-2020-0668 problem

Tags: windows, exploit, attacks

I've been trying to get mentioned security error working on my machine so I could fully understand how it works. I've been following those instructions: https://itm4n.github.io/cve-2020-0668-windows-service-tracing-eop/
and using this tools:
https://github.com/googleprojectzero/symboliclink-testing-tools/

1. Create (or copy) a file with a size greater than 0x8000 (32,768) bytes. (Done this)
2. Create a new directory (C:\EXPLOIT\mountpoint\ for example) and set it as a mountpoint to \RPC Control. (It's the point I'm currently having problem with)
3. Create the following symbolic links:
   \RPC Control\RASTAPI.LOG -> \??\C:\EXPLOIT\FakeDll.dll (owner = current user)
   \RPC Control\RASTAPI.OLD -> \??\C:\Windows\System32\WindowsCoreDeviceInfo.dll (Done this)

My point is only to replace any dll inside system32 directory with this bug.
How can I create mountpoint to \RPC Control. Let's say my directory is at C:\EXPLOIT\mountpoint and i want to set it as mountpoint. How can I do this?

Comment: Is the question about mounting a folder in *nix environment? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Its about windows and it's specialist knowledge, no need to clarify. Its a little outside my area of expertise, but have you run createmountpoint from the symbolic testing toolkit?

Comment: I tried running createmountpoint but im not sure if did it well (it was: CreateMountPoint.exe C:\EXPLOIT\mountpoint "\??\RPC Control\" ). After this command junction was created. But it looked like windows couldn't resolve path.

Answer (score -1):

I'm currently working on this as well, I'm not an expert but I think you have to understand the Windows objects part as well, I couldn't find RPC Control till I read about it, you can use the Sysinternals tool WinObj this will show you a bit more.

I was able to use create mount point between two folders but not to an object, there is more details here https://offsec.provadys.com/intro-to-file-operation-abuse-on-Windows.html

Comment: CreateMountPoint works for me i wasnt so sure but i verified with WinObj see screenshot https://ibb.co/VH2WkyP